# Not able to load properties file kept outside the code

Tags: java

```
import static com.crawler.constants.CrawlerConstants;
import static com.crawler.constants.CrawlerConstants.CRAWLER4J;


import java.util.Properties;


public final class Configurations {

    private static Properties prop = new Properties();


    public static String getStringProperty(String key, String defaultValue) {
        if (prop == null || prop.getProperty(key) == null) {
            return defaultValue;
        }
        return prop.getProperty(key);
    }

    public static int getIntProperty(String key, int defaultValue) {
        if (prop == null || prop.getProperty(key) == null) {
            return defaultValue;
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty(key));
    }

    public static short getShortProperty(String key, short defaultValue) {
        if (prop == null || prop.getProperty(key) == null) {
            return defaultValue;
        }
        return Short.parseShort(prop.getProperty(key));
    }

    public static long getLongProperty(String key, long defaultValue) {
        if (prop == null || prop.getProperty(key) == null) {
            return defaultValue;
        }
        return Long.parseLong(prop.getProperty(key));
    }

    public static boolean getBooleanProperty(String key, boolean defaultValue) {
        if (prop == null || prop.getProperty(key) == null) {
            return defaultValue;
        }
        return prop.getProperty(key).toLowerCase().trim().equals("true");
    }

    static {
        try {
            prop.load(Configurations.class.getClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream(CONFIG_DIR + "/" + CRAWLER4J));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            prop = null;
            System.err.println("WARNING: Could not find crawler4j.properties file in class path. I will use the default values.");
        }
    }
}
```

In my try loop above it is not loading crawler4j.properties file. As previously it was like this-

```
try {
                prop.load(Configurations.class.getClassLoader()
                        .getResourceAsStream("crawler4j.properties"));
            }
```

so it was able to load it directly from the src/main/resources folder. But I want to load this crawler4j.properties file kept outside the code in different directory. So I have stored crawler4j.properties file in /my/dir/crawler4j.properties  and this is try loop that I want to modify-

```
try {
                prop.load(Configurations.class.getClassLoader()
                        .getResourceAsStream(CONFIG_DIR + "/" + CRAWLER4J_PROP));
            }
```

And CONFIG_DIR contains \my\dir and CRAWLER4J has crawler4j.properties but somehow it is not loading and it is going to catch exception block. Any suggestions why is it happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to load something as a resource, it must be on the classpath--that's the definition of a resource (give or take).

To load it from a filesystem path, use [`load(InputStream)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29) (or `load(Reader)`).

Comment: u want to say like this...  `prop.load(new FileInputStream(CONFIG_DIR + "/" + CRAWLER4J_PROP));`

Comment: @RaihanJamal Glad you got it working :) Remember to [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so other people with similar issues can find solutions easily :)

Answer (score 0):

So, what kind of exception do you get? FileNotFound? Is this a part of web app or regular java application?

Make sure you have read rights to read the properties file in the directory.

Edit: 
getResourceAsStream returns null if it doesn't find the resource, so as suggested by others:
1. Make sure the properties file is on the classpath.
2. Escape the / -

```
        prop.load(Configurations.class.getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream(CONFIG_DIR + "//" + CRAWLER4J_PROP));
```

Comment: I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: OP is specifically trying to load a file-system file, AFAICT.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely a misconfigured path, in your catch try appending in your System.err statement:

```
e.getMessage();
```

Comment: I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821643/loading-a-configuration-file-from-the-classpath

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find you need to escape the "/" so try using "//". I'm not sure if this is the issue but I had it awhile back and was pulling my hair out trying to figure out why it worked some places and not others.