# Where to keep `java.util.Properties` file and how to access it?

Tags: java

I am adding email sending capability to my web app. SMTP server settings will be read from a `java.util.Properties` file. I wouldn't like to hardcode path to this file.

Where should I keep this file?

How should I access this file?

Comment: Similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/a/4821955/105251

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution:

I have placed `EmailSettings.properties` file into `WebContent\WEB-INF\classes`. This code now works:

```
InputStream inputFile = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("EmailSettings.properties");

Properties emailConfig = new Properties();

emailConfig.load( inputFile );
.
.
.
```

Comment: How do you mean? For other people to see what to do.

Answer (score 3):

A good pattern to follow is to keep your static resources (like property files) under your `WEB-INF/classes/` directory.

That way they can be read from the `classpath` and not accessed by the browser:

for example, put your settings file under `WEB-INF/classes/mail-settings.properties`, and use the following to read it:

```
InputStream is = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("mail-settings.properties");
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(is);
is.close();
```

Comment: There is a password in this file, risky? Can you comment?

Comment: It depends where you keep your source code. A common practice is to read passwords from the environment or an environment specific file outside of source control.

Answer (score 1):

Keep property file in classpath location like in folder : WEB-INF/classes/mail.properties
Here property file is - mail.properties. To read this file you can use below code

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.MissingResourceException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class EmailPropertyReader {
    private static ResourceBundle myResources;  
    public static String FILENAME = "mail";
    static{
        initialize(FILENAME);
    }
    public static void initialize(String propertyFile) throws MissingResourceException
    {
        try{
            myResources = ResourceBundle.getBundle(FILENAME, Locale.getDefault());
        }catch(Exception ex){
            //Logger
        }
        } 
private static String getParameter(String parmName) 
    {
        String param = null;
        try
        {
            param = myResources.getString(parmName) ;

        }catch(Exception e){            
            param = null;
                        //Logger
        }
        if (param != null)
            return param.trim();
        else
            return param;
    }
}
```

You just create object and enter code here use method `getParameter() ->`
For example:

```
mail.properties :
EMAILID=a@a.com
```

then

```
String strEmailid=EmailPropertyReader.getParameter("EMAILID");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep it with your code you may just as well create the Properties instance programmatically.

```
    Properties mailProperties = new Properties();
    mailProperties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    mailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");
    mailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    mailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "false");

    javax.mail.Session.getInstance(mailProperties);
```

If you want to have it in a properties file anyway you can load it as a classpath resource. Have a look at getResourceAsStream in java.lang.Class. Update: see epochs answer for how to do this!

Answer (score -1):

If the settings are stage dependent ,you could set the path to the File via a vm Enviorment varibable.

-DmyPropertyFilePath=....

Also there is a good artikel about loading property files (even so it is a bit Dated) on [Java World](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2003-08/01-qa-0808-property.html)